# Error: Parse error on line 1: {response:{info:{par -^ Expecting 'STRING', '}'

Tags: android, json, web-services

My Json files top portion is as below. Why am I getting above error?

```
{
  response:{
    info:{
      params: "",
      numReturned: 23,
      numFound: 24,
      start: 1,
      limit: 25,
      app: "sdf",
      platform: "dfsfsd",
      size: "sdfsd",
      device: "NexufdsfS"
    },
    data: ...
```

Comment: JSON uses name/value pairs. The names should be Strings, i.e., surrounded by "". Your names such as response, info, params, numFound etc etc aren't surrounded by "". In fact, none of the names shown in your question have "".

Comment: This site will explain pretty much everything you need to know about JSON in one page. http://www.json.org/

Comment: So, how can I remove that error.. I tried below format but stilll giving me same error.   {response:{
info:{params: "null",
numReturned: "23",
numFound: "24",
start: "1",
limit: "25",
app: "ctm",
platform: "android",
size: "phone",
device: "Nexus S"
},
data:

Comment: You have to correct the code which is generating the JSON file.

Comment: Sorry - you didn't understand. The name is before the `:` and the value is after it. It is OK for values to not have "". For instance 23, 24, 1, 25 are ints and should NOT have surrounding "". It is the names that need to be surrounded by "". Example "response", "info", "params" etc etc.

Comment: Thank you! That helps but here is the thing, I have one webservice which has been provided to me. which has the same format as I mentioned in the question.That is parsing perfectly fine in an android application. Now, what I am doing is, I am coping it and putting it on my own webhosting cause  I can't use the live api all the time. SO, while development I can use static webservice from my own webhosting.  Both has the above format then why I am not getting issue in the api provided to me. How can I copy the live api and put it on my own webhosting just for development purpose?

Comment: **"...has the same format as I mentioned in the question.That is parsing perfectly fine in an android application."** : It shouldn't parse. The format you show in your question isn't valid JSON. If you look at the link I posted in my second comment you'll see the format of a JSON object is `{ string : value, ... }`. If you then look in the right-hand column which defines valid syntax you'll she that `string` is defined as `""` or `"chars"`. In other words the 'name' (string) of a JSON object MUST be surrounded with "". I don't know of any JSON parser which would parse your JSON correctly.